# The context cannot be used while the model is being created.But I've only one dbcontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, dbcontext

I have an ASP.net MVC project which uses EF. I created entities also repository part. In my localhost, everything is fine and works without any problem. But when I removed this project to webhost, something is going wrong I guess.

"The context cannot be used while the model is being created.this exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accepted by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Not everytime but sometimes I get this error when I try to connect my website.

Here is my Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<T> :  IDataAccess<T> where T : class
{
    private DatabaseContext context;
    private DbSet<T> _objectSet;

    public Repository()
    {
        context = RepositoryBase.CreateContext();
        _objectSet = context.Set<T>();
    }



    public List<T> List()
    {
        return _objectSet.ToList();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> ListQueryable()
    {
        return _objectSet.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public List<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where(where).ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my RepositoryBase.cs

```
public class RepositoryBase
{
    private static DatabaseContext context;
    private static object _lockSync = new object();

    protected RepositoryBase()
    {

    }

    public static DatabaseContext CreateContext()
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            lock (_lockSync)
            {
                if (context == null)
                {
                    context = new DatabaseContext();
                }
            }

        }

        return context;
    }
}
```

and my DatabaseContext :

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Soru> Sorular { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Kategori> Kategoriler { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tahmin> Tahminler { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Oneri> Oneriler { get; set; }


    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
    }
}
```

I researched this problem but unfortunately, I couldn't fix it. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You sure that your connection string is correct?

Comment: Do you have `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` in your connection string? If not, try adding it.

Comment: Yes, MultipleActiveResultSets=true

Comment: ConnectionString : <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Server=184.168.194.51;Database=******DB;uid=******;pwd=******;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 2):

Your `DatabaseContext` instance is declared as `static` within the `RepositoryBase` class.

```
private static DatabaseContext context;
```

Because of this, all concurrent requests share the same instance, 
resulting in multiple simultaneous operations on the `DbContext`from different threads,
which is not supported.

Rework your code so that each request has its own instance 
eg, by removing the static keyword.
If each request has its own instance, there's no need anymore to apply a lock.

Also make sure to call the `Dispose` method on the `DbContex` when it isn't needed anymore, eg. at the end of the webrequest.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for the answer.But when i try to declare context instance is just public(without static) it throws "an entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntitiyChangeTracker." So does it mean " Singleton pattern depends on static DatabaseContext instance " ?

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me about this situation.

Comment: Such an error occurs when an entity gets retrieved from a `DbContext`, having some changes applied upon it, and then being saved by an other `DbContext`. To solve this we need to see more and other code where you are doing such a read and save. I suggest you start by searching for this error on this website; there are very good answers here that address that issue. If not, start a new question with more details, so we can help you out. It would make this question and answer too broad. Anyway, not using a singleton/static `DbContext` certainly is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you pfx for help.This was my first topic on stackoverflow and you were the only guy who efforts to help, thx :)

Comment: I'm always in for a challenge ;) Such a concurrency issue is not always easy to spot.